# Why is my rspec test failing for user confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rspec

Here is the failing test:

```
context "when password does not match confirmation" do
  before { build(:user, :password_confirmation => 'mismatch') }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

I am using Factory Girl's `build` method for this test suite.

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

UPDATE:  you don't need to mark :password field with :confirmation => true when using has_secure_password. It's taken care of: see source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb

The validation is working just fine - I get the right error message when I try creating a new user at the console. So why is the test failing? Where is the bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation is not working just fine, you are not validating that the `password_confirmation` matches the `password`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#confirmation for more information.

Also, you need to make sure that you're actually testing what you want to be testing - your subject for these tests is `build(:user)` when it needs to be the `build(:user, password_confirmation: 'mismatch')`. Change the `before` in your above code to a `subject`, to set the subject for the test correctly.

Comment: so where should I place `:confirmation => true`?

Comment: As the guide states, in the validations for whatever field you want to validate the confirmation of.

Comment: updated code above, Its still not working - test keeps failing

Comment: what is the subject of your test?

Comment: `subject { build(:user) }`

Comment: so in other words, not the user you're building with the mismatched password_confirmation? ;)

Comment: aah - you're right - so how do I do this? A little confused at the moment. My setup is wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23027/discussion-between-sevenseacat-and-amit-erandole)